# Required fields in React-Native

Tags: react-native, field, user-input, textinput, required

I am checking some user input values if they are empty and if yes then I looping through their titles (textinput title) and checking if they contain '*'. If they do, I display a message to the user.
However, my approach isnt really working for some reasons. It just continues further even if the user doesnt fill out the required fields. 
What am I doing wrong here?

```
for (i = 0; i < this.myInputFields.myTextFields.length; i++) {
            data[this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i].key] = this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i].inputValues; //there is a bug here, if user doesnt fill the first textinput it will fail to send

            if (this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i].inputValues === '') {
                if (this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i].title.every('*')) {
                    return Alert.alert('Please fill out the required fields!')
                }
            }
        }
```

If the user doesnt give an input in the first TextInput, that fails the operation and displays an error which says that '`this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i].key`' is not defined. It is obviously failing because it is finding the array empty and in fact it expects there to a be a value. But how can I make it continue even that one is empty?

Comment: can u show all the code for the component

Comment: Are your inputs controlled or uncontrolled components? If you could share the entire component it would be much easier to help.

Comment: Possibly because you are doing a strict comparison with `''`.
If those values are not initialized to an empty string that assertion will fail and the inner block will never execute

Comment: what does this checking method look like? It might be just `return Alert.alert('Please fill out the required fields!')` is not enough to halt the operation. It could also be that you call screen transition regardless of the validation return value. Please be aware that retruning Alert.alert() is basically returning undefined, so idk if thats what u want

Comment: Trevor made a good point, you should use an empty checker as such ```export function isEmpty(str) {
    if (str && str.replace(/\ /g, '') !== '')
        return false;
    else {
        return true;
    }
}``` to really check for empty field

Comment: @RayJonathan in React-Native, Return will halt the operation. I managed to do it correctly once but that was failing if the user doesnt give an input in the first textinput. So, it doesnt fail only if the user writes something in the first required field and leaves the second one empty. I am updating the question as it seems the main bug is somewhere else.

Comment: @bimixbimix Ur right, but IF the whole code u posted here is within a separate function and u called it from somewhere else, doing return in the for loop will only halt that particular function, not the entire flow of ur program, so in the end, u still need a meaningful return value for the caller to decide what to do after validation fails and Alert displayed. After re-reading ur update, I would say u could try something like `for (i = 0; i < this.myInputFields.myTextFields.length; i++) { var key = this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i].key; if (key){ ... //rest of ur code in the loop}}`?

Comment: this way the entire statement in the for loop will only be executed if `this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i]` is not null/undefined

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the value of `this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i].inputValues` with `''` explicitly. This will fail if `inputValues` is anything other than `''`. (`undefined` for example)

```
...
if (this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i].inputValues === '')
...
```

instead, just check for falsiness:

```
...
if (!this.myInputFields.myTextFields[i].inputValues)
...
```

Comment: I cant because when i push the user input values to the array, I am only pushing the ones that the user is filling out, not the ones that are left empty. So the loop will go only through the ones that are already filled out thus it wont find any empty! The problem will be solved if I push all textinputs to the array, the empty and the filled ones, so then I can check which one is empty and Alert the user.